# How do I convert a Hash to a JSON string in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, json, hash

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > require 'json'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > hash = {hi: "sup", yo: "hey"}
 => {:hi=>"sup", :yo=>"hey"} 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > hash.to_json
 => "{\"hi\":\"sup\",\"yo\":\"hey\"}"
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > j hash
{"hi":"sup","yo":"hey"}
 => nil
```

`j hash` puts the answer I want but returns `nil`.

`hash.to_json` returns the answer I want with backslashes. I don't want backslashes.

Comment: I updated the question with the STDOUT & return values.

Comment: Wonderful, I didn't j existed. We use y often for formatting Hashes and Objects.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

That's just because of `String#inspect`. There are no backslashes. Try:

```
hjs = hash.to_json
puts hjs
```

Answer (score 14):

You're on the right track. `to_json` converts it to JSON format. Don't let the IRB output fool you -- it doesn't contain any backslashes.

Try this:
`puts hash.to_json`
and you should see this:
`{"hi":"sup","yo":"hey"}`

Answer (score 5):

I don't have Ruby1.9 to test, but apparently you are getting the "inspect" view. Those backslashes are not there, they are just escaping the quotes. Run `puts hash.to_json` to check.